# what does inverse and cascade means in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm learning Fluent Nhibernate and my question is:
What does `Inverse` mean? I read that it means that the other side of the relationship is responsible for the saving, and so does `Cascade`,

Can someone please explain what are the differences between them?
Please explain in details because I'm a newbie at NH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation when Inverse = false is necessary.
If I want a Parent with collection of "children" and in the child object there won't be
a reference to the parent.
so you do Has many on the parent add inverse = false and not adding the reference in the child.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this text](http://swik.net/itefforts/itefforts+blog/Understanding+%22inverse%22+mapping+attribute/bo772) *(link down, here's a [mirror on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20080415101633/http://simoes.org/docs/hibernate-2.1/155.html))*, the "inverse" attribute is explained in detail.

The different cascade options are well explained by Ayende himself in [his blog](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/12/02/nhibernatecascadesthedifferentbetweenallalldeleteorphansandsaveupdate.aspx).

A good and recommended read is "[NHibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/kuate/)", while not an easy text, this will cover a lot of your questions.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand how does inverse = false works I just saw it does stupid things but what is the explanations for it. And when inverse= false is good? Thanks alot!

Comment: Inverse just defines which end of the relationship "owns" it. With set to false (on the one-side), the parent owns the relationship. In most cases, this doesn't make sense and also results in additional, unnecessary SQL statements.

Comment: The first link is down at the moment. Here's a mirror on archive.org https://web.archive.org/web/20080415101633/http://simoes.org/docs/hibernate-2.1/155.html

Comment: As the link is down and an archive link is given (which is very slow to load), including the text in the answer would help.