# Nhibernate bind to DataGridView

Tags: nhibernate, datagridview

Why there is no any tutorial about binding `NHibernate` to `DataGridView` in `Winforms`. Only I want to use it?
I know that this is matter of binding collection to DataGridView. But I have problems with making CRUD.

I have database SQLite+table with mapping:

```
 <class name="Employee" table="emplyees" lazy="true">
    <id name="id">
      <generator class="increment"></generator>
    </id>

    <property name="first_name" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="last_name" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="login" not-null="true"></property>
    <property name="sid"></property>         
</class>
```

Code that works.

```
Employee new_employee =
    new Employee() { first_name = "test1", last_name = "test3", login = "login1" };
session.Save(new_employee);
session.Commit();
```

But if I bind to DataGridView and use grid to insert a new row:

```
transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
employees = (from e in session.Linq<Employee>() select e).ToList<Employee>();
this.employeeBindingSource.DataSource = employees;


private void employeeDataGridView_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
Employee new_employee = (Employee)this.employeeBindingSource.Current;
session.Save(new_employee);
}
```

After `session.Commit()` I get an error: `Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect).` In logs i see that NH sends UPDATE for that new row. Should be insert.

Comment: public properties should be in this format => UpperCase. So FirstName not first_name. **standards** you know...

Answer (score 0):

*Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)*

That `Employee` probably have an id, thus NHibernate "thinks" it should be updated, but NHibernate doesn't find it, so NH transaction thinks the Employee was deleted in some other transaction.

That `id` property has a value and not the default value.  make sure `new_employee.id = 0;`

Comment: Ok. I know what happened. I don't saw exception thrown by session.Save(new_employee); saying that my properties are null. So I  put empty string before Save. I don't know what is best practice but I think not-null checking should be deferred to commit.

Comment: And now it works. I see new record after commit. I only wonder why NH sends INSERT and after it UPDATE of same record.

Comment: @userbb. That update is an other issue. read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883900/what-does-inverse-and-cascade-means-in-nhibernate) post here. hope it helped.